# Storage Access Framework and native code

Tags: java, android, c, file-io, java-native-interface

I want to develop an App that uses the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) but processes the provided files with JNI native code.

Via the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) I get a `Uri` after a call to `startActivityForResult()` with a `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` intent. From this I can get an `InputStream`, `ParcelFileDescriptor` or similar.

Is there a way to get from this something (like for example a `FILE`) that I can pass on to my native code so that it can directly read from/write to the file provided by the content provider?

Background:

The C part of the JNI interface (which I didn't write but can modify/extend) can load two kinds of data

1. files specified by a file name `const char *filename` that can be opened with `open()`
2. data in a buffer `jbyteArray array` containing the bytes that make up the "file"

and can write to

1. a file path `const char *filename` that can be opened with `fopen()`

Currently, when opening a file with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` the `Uri uri` obtained in `onActivityResult()` is converted to an input stream with `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` and then read into a `byte[] buffer` which is passed to the native code. Once the native code is done, it saves the result to a temporary file whose path is passed back to the Java side. The Java code then reads the temporary file and puts its content into a `FileOutputStream` obtained from the `uri`.

This is obviously horribly inefficient and ugly.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this? I have similar problem,  I need to access files on external sdcard by absolute path from native code. I thought I can grant access to the sdcard by SAF and then it will be accessible and writable, but it seems it's not possible... Thanks.

Comment: No. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a slick solution for this.

Comment: maybe this will help you : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30593964/how-to-access-android-lollipop-documentfile-files-via-ndk/31677287)