# How to access Android Lollipop DocumentFile files via NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop

How is it possible to access files which are generated from a [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html) in Android KitKat/Lollipop in Native JNI Code, so I can use fopen, fread, etc.
I'm particular asking this to access the external SD-Card files via the NDK.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59004193/3768831

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use file descriptors:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor filePfd;
DocumentFile file;
filePfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(file.getUri(), "w");
int fd = filePfd.getFd();
```

This int `fd` can be passed to JNI and used as usual C++ file descriptor:

```
FILE* file = NULL;
file = fdopen(fd, "r+b");
```

And you need permission to access to file or directory on SD-card

Comment: Do you need to do a fclose for the fdopen? or would this create a problem when closing the file descriptor?

Comment: @PerracoLabs File Pointer and File Descriptor are different entities. So, I think, you need to do fclose(). But the best way to find out is to test it. Also you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423628/whats-the-difference-between-a-file-descriptor-and-file-pointer

Comment: @PerracoLabs calling fclose would be a bad idea as it does an implied `close` and when the Java side gets control it will also do a `close` because `getFd()` does not transfer ownership.  The Java code could call `detachFd()` instead then calling `fclose` on the native side would be okay.  the only thing is if an error path prevents the native code from getting to the `fdopen` the `fd` needs to be freed still.  The other option might be to do `fdopen(dup(fd), "r+b")` on the native side instead (note the call to `dup`) and then call `fclose` on the file pointer.